# How to set presetted values from a list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, local

I'm working on app which calculates fees. Trouble is that US got different fees than Germany, France got different fees than UK, ecc...
I'd like to do a voice in preferences where people can set their nation and, my app, when calculates fees, get nation's fees ...a kind of localization

Something like this:

```
          -> USA -> archive of USA's local fees -> local fees applied during elaboration
         / 
settings --> UK -> archive of UK's local fees -> local fees applied during elaboration
         \
          -> France -> archive of french's local fees -> local fees applied during elaboration
```

How can do this?
Thank you a lot, Matteo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming). . .

- Create a protocol or base class with the methods to calculate the fees, and then an implementation for each country you wish to support.
- Store the user's preference in some where like NSUserDefaults . . suggest using an enum.
- Use a factory to retrieve an instance of the object conforming to the protocol, where the argument is the user's country.

Comment: Good to hear! Please vote/accept the answer if you found it useful.